# Convert Leaflet LatLng to x,y pixels image overlay

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map created from an image using imageOverlay for indoor map rendering purposes, I'm wondering given the leaflet latitudes and longitudes how to get the x,y pixels of the image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest conversion for setting and getting pixel coordinates from Lat/Lng system is to use:

1. Project: to convert from lat/lng to pixels `project(<LatLng> latlng, <Number> zoom)`
2. Unproject: to convert from pixels to lat/lng `unproject(<Point> point, <Number> zoom)`

Always you can refer to [Leaflet reference](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#map-project)

> P.S: consider the Map CRS is set to Simple

Comment: The link seems to have changed to https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#projection

Answer (score 1):

Check [Non-geographical maps tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) for using CRS Simple coordinate reference system.
This way you can use lat-long concepts like x-y offset on images.